# Get anti-diagonal of a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Numpy array and I would like to get it's reversed diagonal...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.eye(6, dtype=int)
>>> arr
... array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

I know that in order to get the diagonal i can do this:

```
>>> arr.diagonal()
... array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

But i would like to get it's anti-diagonal.

```
>>> flipped_arr = np.fliplr(arr)
>>> flipped_arr
... array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Here is what happens when i try to get the diagonal of `flipped_arr`:

```
>>> flipped_arr.diagonal()
... array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: `flipped_arr.diagonal()` gets the diagonal elements along `flipped_arr`, which are the anti-diagonal elements in `arr`. With `flipped_arr.diagonal()`, you are expecting to get anti-diagonal ones from `flipped_arr`, which is a wrong assumption.

Comment: @Divakar Is there a way to get the anti-diagonal elements?

Comment: You already have it - `np.fliplr(arr).diagonal()` gets the anti-diagonal elements of `arr`, if it wasn't clear in earlier comment.

Comment: Instead of using ```flipped_arr.diagonal()``` use `np.diag(np.fliplr(flipped_arr))`. Hope this Helpful !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you would like to get the antidiagonal, you seem to have the solution already

```
def anti_diagonal(arr):
    return np.fliplr(arr).diagonal()
```

So for a matrix like

```
[[0, 0, 1],
 [0, 2, 0],
 [3, 0, 0]]
```

then the `anti_diagonal` would be

```
 [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've already answered your own question.

```
np.fliplr(arr).diagonal()
```

is the reversed diagonal of `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need small change..

```
 import numpy as np
 arr = np.eye(6, dtype=int)
 arr
 array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
 arr.diagonal()
 array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Your anti-diagonal is like ..

```
 flipped_arr = np.fliplr(arr)
 flipped_arr
 array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Now you need to print diagonal of flipped_arr.

Here is the code for getting diagonal of flipped_arr..

```
np.diag(np.fliplr(flipped_arr))

#array[1,1,1,1,1,1] - Output
```

Hope this Helpful !

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.diagonal` returns a copy rather than a view for some versions of numpy, and may also be read-only. You can construct a view of the anti-diagonal with slicing:

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> print(a)
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]

>>> x = a.ravel()[2:-1:2]
>>> print(x)
[2 4 6]

# modify 'x' and 'a' changes since x is a view
>>> x += 10
>>> print(a)
[[ 0  1 12]
 [ 3 14  5]
 [16  7  8]]
```